# Selenium grid + PNUnit parallel tests

Tags: c#, selenium-grid, pnunit

I am trying to execute tests in parallel in multiple browser in .Net ecosystem
using Selenium Grid and PNUnit as framework.

I have established the hub and nodes but I am not able to execute the tests in parallel. Can someone help me with this issue or point me to a resource from which I can learn to execute parallel tests across machines/browsers using PNUnit?

I also read a lot about Gallio but again I am not finding a tutorial that explains how to establish the tests to run on multiple machines.

Thanks,
Shaun

Answer (score -1):

I don't think PNUnit is designed for this sort of thing,  from the NUnit website :

> PNUnit is not intended for "casual" parallelism merely to make the tests run faster. Rather, it's intended as a way to test applications composed of distributed, communicating components.

I would write the test to take an argument specifying the browser to use then:

If you are running these tests from a CI server, look into parallel tasks for it, and pass in the browsers you want to test to these tasks. I know that CruiseControl.NET has these.

If you are running this manually, just write a batch script that fires off as many test runners as you have browsers to test

Comment: A down vote with no comment? How am I supposed to improve this answer  if I don't know what you think is wrong?